# angular class not updating when corresponding condition changed

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I've created a text input like below:

```
<input 
    id="tenancyName" 
    #tenancyName="ngModel" 
    class="register__form__control" 
    autoFocus 
    type="text" 
    placeholder="Business Name" 
    [(ngModel)]="model.tenancyName"
    name="tenancyName" 
    required 
    maxlength="64" />
```

and after my input, I have a div which is a warning that the business name they have entered is already taken.

```
<div [class.taken]="taken === true" class="register__warning">
    <p>Sorry, Business Name is already taken</p>
</div>
```

then in my component.ts

```
import ... from ...

import * as _ from 'lodash';

@component...
export class...

  taken: boolean;

  ngOnInt() {
    const businessInput = <HTMLInputElement>document.getElementById('tenancyName');
    businessInput.addEventListener('keyup', _.debounce(this.checkTenantName, 1000));

  }

  checkTenantName() {
    this.taken = true;
  }
```

so basically, what is happening is that I'm using the `debounce` function from `lodash` to call a function after the user has stopped typing for 1s now the function does fire but the `register__warning` doesn't get the `.taken` class

Im not sure what im doing wrong.. any help would be appreciated

**EDIT**

I have put a console.log() in the checkTenantName() function like so

```
checkTenantName() {
    this.taken = true;
    console.log(this.taken);
}
```

and I get true returned in console.. so Im not sure why my div wouldn't be getting the `.taken` class

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to access the correct \`this\` inside a callback?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20279484/how-to-access-the-correct-this-inside-a-callback)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are accessing `this` which means for the **component class** itself, so you need to keep original context while running `checkTenantName` function via `bind(this)` or use arrow function.

```
// use bind(this)
businessInput.addEventListener('keyup', _.debounce(this.checkTenantName.bind(this), 1000));
// use arrow function
businessInput.addEventListener('keyup', _.debounce(() => this.checkTenantName(), 1000));
```

Refer **[demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-c9mo4d?file=src/app/app.component.ts)**.

Comment: Hey thanks! I didn't even think about `this` being the problem

Comment: @JuvenileSnow You are welcome. You can check by console `this` itself to see whether it is the correct one. :-)